# About PHP manager file

Tags: php

How about this function? 
What does foreach and rmdir($file) do in this code?

```
function rmDirectory($dir)
{
    foreach (glob($dir . '/*') as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) 
           rmdir($file); 
        else 
           unlink($file);
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

Comment: `rmdir($dir)` wont rekursivly delete the folder, so you have to find all sub files/folders before and delete them first, thats why you have the foreach with `rmdir($file)`. $file can be an subfolder here.

Answer (score 1):

The **foreach** construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays of $dir.

**glob** — Find pathnames matching a pattern

**rmdir** — Removes directory

Answer (score 0):

Delete all files and empty directories under `$dir`

If the `$dir` is empty, delete it

Answer (score 0):

> The glob() function returns an array of filenames or directories
>   matching a specified pattern.

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_glob.asp). Your foreach traverses each items found at the pattern specified as parameter. For each of them, [is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) checks whether they are directories. If the current `$file` happens to be a directory, then it is removed using [rmdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php), otherwise it is a file and is removed using [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php). Finally `$dir` is removed as well.

`rmDirectory` essentially removes the content (folders and files) of a directory and then removes the directory itself.

Comment: @amir you are welcome. If the answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... what's the difference between folder and directory ?

Comment: @amir there is no difference. A folder is a directory and vice versa.